# add elemets to array using { ? : }

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, conditional-operator

```
    int res[] = new int[]{(num1< num2 ? num1, num2 : num2 , num1)};
```

I'm trying to insert two integers into an array!
the element should be smaller and the second element should be larger.
arrays.sort() not  good idea!;
simple old techniques are known I needed a new solution like ternary!

how do I need to inset two arrays while checking using the ternary operator?
is this possible to use ternary in {} while adding elements into the array. does the compiler understand what I'm trying to do?

in eclipse I'm getting:

Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error on token ",", . expected
- The primitive type int of num1 does not have a     field num2
- Syntax error on token ",", . expected

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
int res[] = new int[]{Math.min(num1, num2), Math.max(num1, num2)};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do either of this:

```
int res[] = new int[]{Math.min(num1, num2), Math.max(num1, num2)};
```

OR

```
int res[] = num1 < num2 ? new int[]{num1, num2} : new int[]{num2, num1};
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional expression (ternary) consists of a condition and two subexpressions ([JLS Chapter 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)).

In Java the fragments `num1, num2` and `num2, num1` are not valid expressions. The comma `,` is only ever a separator in Java, unlike for example `C` or `JavaScript` where the comma `,` can also be an operator.

Note that even in languages where the comma `,` can act as operator (C, C++, JavaScript) your code fragment would not have the desired outcome (JavaScript documentation for the [Comma operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), in C the effect is the same):

> The comma operator (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So using something like your experiment in JavaScript or C would result in an array of length 1 which contains the larger of the two values.

Answer (score 1):

This could also work:

```
int[] res = new int[] {(a<b ? a : b), (a>b? a : b)};
```